# Least upper bound on $x_n = \min{|a - b\sqrt{3}| : a + b = n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, diophantine-approximation

For all integers $n \geq 1$, define $x_n = \min{|a - b\sqrt{3}| : a + b = n}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Find the smallest positive real number p such that $x_n \leq p$ for all $n \geq 1$.

This problem is problem 1.6.9 from Problems in Analysis : Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis by Teodora-Liliana Radulescu, Vicentiu Radulescu, and Titu Andreescu.

I tried looking at $|a - b\sqrt{3}| = |b||\frac{a}{b}-\sqrt{3}|$ and $|a - b\sqrt{3}|^2=|a^2 - 2ab\sqrt{3}+3b^2|$, but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Because of equidistribution I would expect this number to be $p=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Numerical evidence agrees with @ThomasPreu's conjecture, with the sequence of $n$'s given by the solutions of the Pell equation $x^2-3n^2=1$, namely $\{4, 15, 56, 209, 780, 2911,\dots\}$, providing examples that seem to be converging to $\frac{1+\sqrt3}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt 3+1, x \in (2,3)$ so $x_n=\min |n-bx|, 1 \le b \le n-1$. Let $f_n(y)=f(y)=|n-yx|, 1 \le y \le n-1$.

If we choose $b_1=[n/x], b_2=[n/x]+1$ we have that (for $n \ge 10$ say so $b_1,b_2 \in [1, n-1]$) $b_1x < n <b_2x$ so $f(b_1)+f(b_2)=x$ hence $x_n = \min (f(b_1), f(b_2)) \le x/2$

(since $f_n$ attains it's minimum at $n/x$ and is monotonic on each of the intervals $[1,n/x]$ and $[n/x, n-1]$ it follows that indeed $x_n$ is attained at either $[n/x]$ or $[n/x]+1$)

But now since $1/x$ is irrational, we have that $n/x$ is equidistributed modulo $1$ hence for every $\epsilon >0$ there are infinitely many $n$ st $0 < n/x-[n/x] -1/2 \le \epsilon$.

Hence $f_n([n/x])=x(n/x-[n/x]) \in [x/2, x/2+x\epsilon]$ which shows that for those $n$ we have that $f_n([n/x]+1)=x-f_n([n/x]) \ge x/2-x\epsilon$, hence $x_n =\min (f_n([n/x]), f_n([n/x]+1)) \ge x/2-x\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this gives that $\sup x_n =x/2=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2}$ as guessed

Note that as mentioned in the comments for small $n$ it may be that $n/x<1$ so one of the $b$ used to prove the result is not valid being $0$ But here this happens only for$n=2$ and there we check that indeed $|2-x|$ which is the only value hence the min by default is indeed less than $(1+x)/2$ since $x<3$ so we are good

Comment: You are right about $x \in(2,3)$ -and will correct it; the point you make is that for small $n$ it may happen that the infimum is higher since $n/x$ is smaller than $1$ so $[n/x]=0$ which is not a valid $b$ ( the proof uses that for two valid $b_1,b_2$ we have the sum is $x$ so one is at most $x/2$ and it fails if one is not valid of course which for $x>1$ can happen only at small $n$) so yes one needs to check that case separate but here $n=2$ is the only such and for that we get $|2-x|$ which is less that $(x+1)/2$ since $x<3$

Comment: @Thomas That was a good point though, namely that for general irrational $\theta$ the same result is correct with $x=1+\theta$ only if $1<\theta<2$ which conveniently holds for $\sqrt 3$; otherwise we need some modifications to account for small values of $n$ (eg we can ask for lim sup rather than sup etc)